# Bootstrap Modal print - switch of overflow and position for other modals

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I do have three modals and for one I need the following css to print out the modal (because it can be more than one page)
For other modal I do not need this css. 
Is there a possibility either to set this css only for specific modals or to switch of for specific modals?

```
.modal,
.modal * {
    overflow: hidden; !important;
}
.modal {
    position: inherit !important;
}
```

Comment: You ca add id? Please describe your problem more. for example `id="modal1"` and for other modal set the `id="modal2"` and in css use `#modal1` and `#modal2`.

Comment: I can not access the **class="modal"** because it is from bootstrap. Is there an other possibility?

Comment: You can still use id's. And you can add other classes also e.g class="thisShouldNotHaveTheCss". You can also store the bootstrap.css locally and change things from there.